# Swift UIView subclass with auto layout

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I am creating a new custom UIView subclass, where I want to use Auto Layout for that view. That view contains a label. My custom view should automatically resize depending on the text size. My confusion is, does that work and do I have to initialize my custom view with a frame?

```
class CustomView : UIView
{
    var label : UILabel = UILabel()
    
    var text : String = ""
    
    init(text: String)
    {
        super.init(frame: .zero)

        self.text = text
        
        setupView()
        setupLayout()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("This class does not support NSCoding")
    }
    
    func setupView() -> Void
    {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 85.0/255.0, green: 88.0/255.0, blue: 91.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        
        //Create main label
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = self.text
        label.textColor = .white
        label.font = label.font.withSize(12.0)
        label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.textAlignment = .left
        self.label = label
        addSubview(label)
    }
    

    override class var requiresConstraintBasedLayout: Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    func setupLayout() -> Void
    {
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
            heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200)
        ])
    }
}
```

This is what I tried.. I have created a own `init()` method, where I pass frame zero to the super init. Is that correct? I want the size to be done by auto layout depending on the text. Or do I need to set constraints in my parent view, where CustomView is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you giving the label heightAnchor?

If you want it to be automatically resized depends on the text all you to do is:

1. numberOfLines is 0 for the label
2. give top,leading,bottom and trailing anchors for the label to its super view
3. super view should at least has top,leading and trailing anchors to its super view (View controller view) where you are going to add this custom view.

DONT forget while init the custom view set the property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false

Comment: Thank you. Setting translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false in the init of my custom view did the trick! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's alright to set the initial frame of the custom view to `.zero`.

If you want to achieve an auto-sizing custom view, and in your case, the label indicates the desired size of the view, you can leverage the `intrinsicContentSize` of the label and set it for your container view.

```
override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    label.intrinsicContentSize
}
```

This way, all you need to do is to set the **origin** of your custom view upon creation. The rest will be managed by AutoLayout automatically. Also, you don't even need to set the origin, when you add your custom view to a UIStackView for example. In other words, your view acts like a UILabel now.

That being said, you can now safely remove the unnecessary constraints of your UILabel and let the superview handle the rest:

```
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
        label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor)
    ])
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried it and the label does size well, however my view is not visible. There is no background color at all. I have set frame to zero, and I only can see the label. Not the view

Comment: It needs more context (code) to know what's going on, but most probably, you haven't set the constraints for your custom view once you added it as a subview. this solution just guarantee a self sizing view. The rest has to be done outside of your view (adding constraints etc). Try setting a constant frame size and see if it works, I suspect that your view frame is `zero`, but you see the label because the view's `clipsToBounds` property is false by default!

Comment: Also try to call `layoutIfNeeded` to let the system redraw the view once more.